# Using if statements with strings in c++

Tags: c++, if-statement, c-strings

I am trying to perform binary addition using strings. When using if statement, I am always getting the output "did not go in ifs". Please help me and tell me if I am doing any bad practice or any error. Beginner in c++.

```
while(k >= 0)
{
    if (Bin_input1[k] == 0 && Bin_input2[k] == 0)
    {
        if (carry == 0)
        {
            Bin_output[k] = 0;
            cout <<Bin_output[k] << endl;
            carry = 0;
            k = k-1;
        }
        else
        {
            Bin_output[k] = 1;
            cout <<Bin_output[k] << endl;
            carry = 0;
            k = k-1;
        }
    }
    else if (Bin_input1[k] == 0 && Bin_input2[k] == 1)
    {
        if (carry == 0)
        {
            Bin_output[k] = 1;
            cout <<Bin_output[k] << endl;
            k = k-1;
        }
        else
        {
            Bin_output[k] = 1;
            cout <<Bin_output[k] << endl;
            carry = 1;
            k = k-1;
        }
    }
    else if (Bin_input1[k] == 1 && Bin_input2[k] == 0)
    {
        if (carry == 0)
        {
            Bin_output[k] = 1;
            cout <<Bin_output[k] << endl;
            k = k-1;
        }
        else
        {
            Bin_output[k] = 1;
            cout <<Bin_output[k] << endl;
            carry = 1;
            k = k-1;
        }
    }
    else if (Bin_input1[k] == 1 && Bin_input2[k] == 1)
    {
        {
            Bin_output[k] = 1;
            cout <<Bin_output[k] << endl;
            carry = 1;
            k = k-1;
        }
    }
    else
        cout<< "did not go in ifs" << endl ;

    k = k - 1;
}
return Bin_output;
```

Comment: I'm going to go with `0 != '0'`.

Comment: What is `Bin_input1`? If it's an array of `char`, you don't want to be comparing to 0 and 1.

Comment: Cannot compile and test that...

Comment: @PhilipKendall Bin_input1 is a string and so is Bin_input2 and Bin_output

Comment: @chris : where shall I use != '0', didn't get u

Comment: By "string", do you mean a `std::string`, a `char *` or something else? Please post a full minimal program which shows the problem you're having, not just a fragment.

Comment: @PhilipKendall, it is std::string

Comment: @Kashish, I mean [`'0'` does not have the value 0](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3e14274e87dd8f76).

Comment: @Kashish : Chris was not making a suggestion, rather and assertion: The characters `'0'` and `'1'` do not have the same values as the integers `0` and `1`.

Comment: I'll second @PhilipKendall, when you ask questions about a specific problem you should aim to create a "Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example" (see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

You need to compare the characters with the character constants `'0'` and `'1'` rather than the integer values 0 and 1.  For example:

```
if( Bin_input1[k] == '0' && Bin_input2[k] == '0' )
```

Answer (score 0):

As I have understood the strings contain characters '0' and '1'. They have integer codes (In ASCII) 48 and 49. So you have to compare elements of these strings with these codes or with these symbols '0' and '1'.

The code could look much simpler

```
carry = 0;

while ( k >= 0 )
{
    int sum = ( Bin_input1[k] - '0' ) + ( Bin_input2[k] -'0' ) + carry;

    Bin_output[k] = sum % 2 + '0';
    carry = sum / 2;
    --k;
}
```

Take into account that due to carry the resulted string can be one character larger than the other two strings. You have to process this case.

If Bin_input1 and Bin_input2 have equal lengths then I would write the loop the following way

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

//...

std::string Bin_output;

Bin_output.reserve( Bin_input1.length() + 1 );
int carry = 0;

for ( std::string::size_type i = Bin_input1.size(); i != 0; --i )
{
    int sum = ( Bin_input1[i - 1] - '0' ) + ( Bin_input2[i - 1] - '0' ) + carry;

    carry = sum / 2;

    Bin_output.push_back( sum % 2 + '0' );
}

if ( carry ) Bin_output.push_back( carry );

std::reverse( Bin_output.begin(), Bin_output.end() );
```

Comment: That is obviously a far better algorithm, but it is not an answer to the question.  Clever algorithms are all very well, but understanding the difference between a character constant and a literal integer is perhaps more fundamental.

Comment: @Clifford The algorithm contains the answer to your question. See how I calculate expressions with string characters.

Comment: It is not my question.  I have answered the question directly in another answer.  Converting a digit character to an integer value is not the same thing as comparing a character to a character constant.  It is a better solution to the OP's application, but he did not ask about how to implement the solution, merely why his conditional statements were not resolving to `true`.  If the code he submits is "cleverer" than his tutor knows him to be, he will be open to accusation of plagiarism.

Comment: @clifford I tried using '0' but ut gives the error stating string subscript out of range.

Comment: @Kashish It means that you incorrectly  initializes k or the output string was not properly created. For example k may not be equal to Bin_input1.size().

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, I have checked and re checked for k, nut according to me its okay, but when I use '0', it shows the error (script subscript out of range) at runtime. But, if I use 0 instead of '0', it compiles fine but does not goes into IF part, the loop runs fine but only prints whatever is there in ELSE part

Comment: @Clifford  I have checked and re checked for k, but according to me its okay, but when I use '0', it shows the error (string subscript out of range) at runtime. But, if I use 0 instead of '0', it compiles fine but does not goes into IF part, the loop runs fine but only prints whatever is there in ELSE part

Comment: @Kashish : You seem to misunderstand ,`k` must remain an integer index. See my answer.

Comment: @Kashish '0' and 0 have nothing common with your ptoblem. As I said either you incorrectly defined the output string or incorrectly used the index. Show how you ndefined the output string and how you assigned k.